# SQL Server PowerShell error Get-ChildItem

Tags: sql-server, powershell, get-childitem

I try to get backup from SQL databases with this PowerShell code:

```bsh
Set-Location "SQLSERVER:\SQL\computer\distance\Databases"
foreach ($database in (Get-ChildItem)) {
    $dbName = $database.Name
    Backup-SqlDatabase -Database $dbName -BackupFile "E:\bu\$dbName"
}
```

In a virtual server it works.
When I go to SQLSERVER:\SQL\computer\distance\Databases location and take `ls`
it show my databases and sucessfully takes backups.

But in another server in my workplace it gives this error:

```
Get-ChildItem : SQL Server PowerShell provider error: Failed to read child items.
[Failed to connect to server computer\instance. --> Login failed for user
'work\sql'.]
At line:1 char:23
+ ForEach($database in (Get-ChildItem))
+                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (SQLSERVER:\SQL\...\instance\Databases:SqlPath) [Get-ChildItem], GenericProviderException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotReadChildItems,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

and when in SQLSERVER:\SQL\computer\distance\Databases directory I do `ls` it gives this error:

```
ls : SQL Server PowerShell provider error: Failed to read child items. [Failed to
connect to server computer\instance. --> Login failed for user 'work\sql'.]
At line:1 char:1
+ ls
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (SQLSERVER:\SQL\...\instance\Databases:SqlPath) [Get-ChildItem], GenericProviderException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotReadChildItems,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

computer\instance: I changed for this example.

Comment: `Login failed for user 'work\sql'` -- don't ignore that

Comment: why login failed? i open sql managment with this user and take backup!?

Comment: Have you tried some of the tools here: https://dbatools.io/